# ANT: Force error on missing resource?

Tags: ant, resources, detection

I've inherited an Ant build system that contains many resource
set definitions like this:

```
<files id="app1.lib.jars">
  <include name="${java}/jre/lib/jsse.jar"/>
  <include name="${work.lib}/jtidy.jar"/>
  ...
</files>

<files id="app2.lib.jars">
  <include name="${work.lib}/itext.jar"/>
  <include name="${work.lib}/commons-httpclient.jar"/>
  ...
</files>

<files id="app3.lib.jars">
  <include name="${work.lib}/jdom.jar"/>
  <include name="${ant.lib}/ant.jar"/>
  ...
</files>
```

There are perhaps a dozen of these, and each can contain anywhere from
5 to 50 files.  The problem is that I'm reworking this system to use
Ivy for dependency management, and in the process some of the
references now point to non-existent files.  Unfortunately, Ant does
not provide any help finding these bad pointers.  When these resource
collections are used to define a classpath any `<include...>` tags
pointing to missing files are silently ignored.

I thought I could force an error by using the collections as the
source of a `<copy...>`, but even with `failonerror="true"` it just
ignored the bad references.

The command-line `-v` (verbose) and `-d` (debug) option didn't help
either.  The output acknowledged that some were missing but didn't
actually show them

```
 [echo] app1.lib.jars
 [copy] C:\dev\src\tomcat6\work\java\jre\lib\jsse.jar omitted as C:\dev\src\tomcat6\work\verify\jsse.jar is up to date.
 [copy] C:\dev\src\tomcat6\work\lib\axis-ant.jar omitted as C:\dev\src\tomcat6\work\verify\axis-ant.jar is up to date.
 ...
 [copy] No sources found.
 [echo] app2.lib.jars
 ...
```

For a one-time solution I extracted all the filenames from the
resource sets in the Ant file and compared that to a directory listing
of the result of copying all the files (in Ant) into a temporary
directory, after appropriate sorting.

Question: Is there a way to get Ant to tell me when a resource points
to a missing file, preferably at the time the resource is defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an illustration of one method.  Key points

- Convert your `files` to [filelists](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filelist.html) - these can contain names of files that don't exist in the file system, unlike filesets and files, that ignore entries that don't exist
- Use a [restrict](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#restrict) to check for existence
- Use a `fail` to error when something is missing

You'll need to add the "antlib:org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.selectors" namespace to the project to use the resource selectors shown below.  You'll hit snags with Ant versions older than 1.7.0.

```
<project name="so" default="checkfiles" basedir="."
xmlns:rsel="antlib:org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.selectors">

<filelist id="app1.lib.jars">
  <file name="${java}/jre/lib/jsse.jar"/>
  <file name="${work.lib}/jtidy.jar"/>
  ...
</filelist>

<restrict id="missing.app1.lib.jars">
  <filelist refid="app1.lib.jars"/>
  <rsel:not>
    <rsel:exists/>
  </rsel:not>
</restrict>

<property name="missing.files" refid="missing.app1.lib.jars" />
<fail message="These files are missing: ${missing.files}">
  <condition>
    <length string="${missing.files}" when="greater" length="0" />
  </condition>
</fail>
<pathconvert property="found.files" refid="app1.lib.jars" />
<echo message="Found files ${found.files}" />
```

Alternatively, you could use the 'copy' task, as you suggest, but with filelists instead of files.
The copy should fail when it tries to process the first resource that doesn't exist.

Comment: This solution is not optimal since I would prefer to use the newer resource containers (I find it strange that filelist and fileset haven't been refactored to subclass the containers).  What I really want is an option that will tell Ant to issue warnings for missing files, but that doesn't appear to be available.  Martin's answer looks like the best way to accomplish this for the time being.